# Remove extra blank line added by SP2013 in the top of the masterpage?

Tags: 2013, master-page

I'm working on the seattle.html masterpage for Sharepoint 2013. I want to use the HTML5 Doctype, so I changed the doctype to `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Before the doctype, the page is full of the below crap:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--SPG:

This HTML file has been associated with a SharePoint Master Page (.master file) carrying the same name.  While the files remain associated, you will not be allowed to edit the .master file, and any rename, move, or deletion operations will be reciprocated.

To build the master page directly from this HTML file, simply edit the page as you normally would.  Use the Snippet Generator at https://educate.one.dell.com/_layouts/15/ComponentHome.aspx?Url=https%3A%2F%2Feducate%2Eone%2Edell%2Ecom%2F%5Fcatalogs%2Fmasterpage%2FGSD%5FLD%5F2013%2Fstandard%2Emaster to create and customize useful SharePoint entities, then copy and paste them as HTML snippets into your HTML code.   All updates to this file will automatically sync to the associated Master Page.

-->
```

And this part is then removed in the final rendering in the browser, except for a blank line that is added at the top of the document, just before the DOCTYPE (when you look at the source page):

```
---- empty line -----
<!DOCTYPE html >
```

In some browsers that might cause the browser to misunderstand the DOCTYPE...

I tried to move the `<!DOCTYPE html>` statement in different places but the result is always the same.

I don't think there is anyway to fix it, but maybe someone will have a good idea to help :-)

Comment: I can't understand your question, `<!DOCTYPE html>` does appear in the rendered master page right ?

Comment: In my Sharepoint website I have `<!DOCTYPE html >`  indeed, but it's not at the top of the source, there is blank line just before it. So the file starts by a blank line, and then there is the doctype. I've had this issue before with SP 2010 but I've been able to fix it to have the tag at the first bytes.